# How to override antd style with dva

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-css-modules

I initialized my project with dva

```
// component.js
import React from 'react';
import { Table, Icon } from 'antd';
import styles from '../../style/public.less';
import comStyle from '../../style/company.less';

// company.less
.ant-table {
    border: none!important;
}
```

My style got 'modulized' like this `ant-table-small___2ihaB`
How to override the built-in class?

Comment: disable css-modules.

Comment: @yesmeck Thanks for reply, so there's no official way to bypass it? That's suck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, a colleague helped me with this -- this answer is `:global`, this will override the built-in style globally. Like this:

```less
:global {
  .ant-table {
    border: none;
  }
}
```

If you don't want to override it globally, just nest `:global` in you class and then give this class to the component you want to style.

example:

```less
// myStyle.less
.myClass {
  :global {
    .ant-table {
      border: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// myComponent.js
<Table className={styles.myClass} />
```